# Event handler states method is not given

Tags: c#

Hey guys i'm pretty new to programming and i'm trying to make a basic program what is supposed to calculate the cost of paving, Its my second attempt at this and I have labeled everything correctly but I am still getting an error, could anyone assist me please?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnCalculate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            const double dPAVING_COST = 5.40;

            int iLength;
            int iWidth;
            int iArea;
            double dCost;

            // obtain length from user
            iLength = Convert.ToInt32(txtLength.text);
            // obtain width from user
            iWidth = Convert.ToInt32(txtWidth.Text);


            // calculate area to be paved
            iArea = iWidth * iLength;
            //calculate cost
            dCost = iArea * dPAVING_COST;

            // output the data
            lblDisplay.Text = "Area: " + iArea.ToString("N2")
            + Environment.NewLine
           + " Paving cost: "
            + dCost.ToString("C");

        }

        private void txtWidth(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void lblLength(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void lblWidth(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void lblDisplay(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void txtLength(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The errors do not seem to be showing up on here but this is where they are

iLength = Convert.ToInt32(txtLength.text);

iWidth = Convert.ToInt32(txtWidth.Text);

lblDisplay.Text = "Area: " + iArea.ToString("N2")

Comment: I run your code in the Console app entering the values for length 20 and for width 32 this is what I get in the output
`Area: 640.00
 Paving cost: $3,456.00` so what is the issue.. ? use the debugger to pinpoint your issue.. also change your lblDisplay.Text = to use `string.Format`

Comment: What error? You should read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I tested this in a Console App and I do not get any errors 
make sure that you are entering valid data into your TextBoxs as well here is an example on how to make the string.Format cleaner and more readable 
also change this line `iLength = Convert.ToInt32(txtLength.text);` to 
`iLength = Convert.ToInt32(txtLength.Text);`

```
const double dPAVING_COST = 5.40;

int iLength;
int iWidth;
int iArea;
double dCost;

// obtain length from user
iLength = Convert.ToInt32(20);//replace 20 with txtLength.Text
// obtain width from user
iWidth = Convert.ToInt32(32);//relace 32 with txtWidth.Text


// calculate area to be paved
iArea = iWidth * iLength;
//calculate cost
dCost = iArea * dPAVING_COST;

// output the data
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Area: {0} {1} Paving cost: {2}",iArea.ToString("N2"),
    Environment.NewLine,dCost.ToString("C")));
```